# Binding UIKit with view model using ReactiveCocoa 3/4

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa

I have worked a lot with ReactiveCocoa `2.x.y` and am now playing with migrating to 4.0 (I know it's still in alpha as of this writing).

However, I have a difficult time figuring out how do this:

```
RAC(viewModel, selectedDate) = [[self.view.datePicker rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventsValueChanged] map:^id(UIDatePicker *picker) {
    return picker.date
}];
```

in RC 3 or 4 using Swift. It is as if they haven't yet made the appropriate extensions to UIKit.

I then figured I could maybe do something á la

```
viewModel.selectedDate <~ view.datePicker.rac_signalForControlEvents(.ValueChanged).toSignalProducer().map({ (x) -> NSDate in
    guard let datePicker = x as? UIDatePicker else { return NSDate() }
    return datePicker.date
})
```

where the view model has this property:

```
var selectedDate: MutableProperty<NSDate>
```

but that gives all kinds of compiler errors:

```
Binary operator '<~' cannot be applied to operands of type 'MutableProperty<NSDate>' and 'SignalProducer<NSDate, NSError>'
```

### EDIT

So I have managed to get rid of compiler errors using this:

```
viewModel.selectedDate <~ _mainView.datePicker.rac_signalForControlEvents(.ValueChanged).toSignalProducer()
.flatMapError({ (error) -> SignalProducer<AnyObject?, NoError> in
    return .empty
}).map({ (x) -> NSDate in
    guard let datePicker = x as? UIDatePicker else { return NSDate() }
    return datePicker.date
})
```

but none of this code is ever executed. It seems like the producer is not started correctly, since this *does* get executed:

```
_mainView.datePicker.rac_signalForControlEvents(.ValueChanged).toSignalProducer()
.flatMapError({ (error) -> SignalProducer<AnyObject?, NoError> in
    return .empty
}).map({ (x) -> NSDate in
    guard let datePicker = x as? UIDatePicker else { return NSDate() }
    return datePicker.date
}).startWithNext({ (date) -> () in
    print("\(date)")
})
```

### EDIT 2

To make sure that everything else is working as intended I have this:

```
_mainView.datePicker.rac_signalForControlEvents(.ValueChanged).toSignalProducer().startWithNext { (x) -> () in
    guard let datePicker = x as? UIDatePicker else { return }
    print("\(datePicker.date)")
}
```

which prints out date changes just fint.

### EDIT 3

Further, to make sure the view model property is also fine, I have this:

```
viewModel.selectedDate.producer.startWithNext { (selectedDate) -> () in
    print("Selected date: \(selectedDate)")
}

viewModel.selectedDate = MutableProperty(NSDate())
```

which also prints as expected.

### EDIT 4

My view model looks as follows:

```
class MainViewModel {
    var selectedDate: MutableProperty<NSDate>

    init() {
        selectedDate = MutableProperty(NSDate())
    }
}
```

And my view controller:

```
private var viewModel = MainViewModel()
```

Comment: What compiler errors are you seeing? That code snipper looks correct so I imagine there must be something else that's causing trouble. If you can paste the errors you're getting I might be able to help!

Comment: @NachoSoto Just added the compiler error above.

Comment: @NachoSoto Check out my update above

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is because you can't bind a `producer` that can emit errors, you need to handle them first. Because this is a signal converted from `RACSignal` there is no way of knowing if they can really be emitted, so what I would do is guard against that:

```
viewModel.selectedDate <~ view.datePicker
       .rac_signalForControlEvents(.ValueChanged)
       .toSignalProducer()
       .map { x -> NSDate in
            guard let datePicker = x as? UIDatePicker else { return NSDate() }
            return datePicker.date
       }
       .flatMapErrors { error -> SignalProducer<NSDate, NoError> in
           fatalError("Unexpected error: \(error)")

           return .empty
     }
```

I'd recommend creating an operator in a `SignalProducerType` extension to implement this, something like `assumeNoErrors`.

Comment: So how does this return the date of the DatePicker? @NachoSoto

Comment: @zappel sorry! I updated the example with the full code

Comment: Yes, this is also where I ended myself, however, this is never executed?

Comment: What's never executed?

Comment: The `map` closure. I also have a `startWithNext` to make sure that everything else is working as intended.

Comment: It's possible that the `datePicker` is getting deallocated, completing the `SignalProducer` before it emits anything. Is someone holding a strong reference to `view.datePicker`?

Comment: Is the property `viewModel.selectedDate` being deallocated?

Comment: Can you check the rest of the code? It's not clear how you're creating the original `MutableProperty` that you're binding this producer to.

Comment: That looks correct... sorry, it's hard to tell what's going on at this point. If you can share a project I'm happy to take a look and point to what's wrong :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96732/discussion-between-zappel-and-nachosoto).